# How to allow only logged in users to submit a form?

Tags: parse-platform, acl, roles

In my Parse.com app, I allow users to submit a form to publicly post their information.

I want this functionality to be available only to loggedin users with accounts in the app.

I've poked around in Roles, and ACLs but it's not clear if this is what they are for. For instance, I'm not looking for a specific "role" per se. The "role" is simply being logged in, and there is no option to this end.

Any pointers would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: which sdk is in use ( Rest, android, ios .... )

Comment: @RobertRowntree Javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see ParseUser docs (API) and look at 'getSessionToken()' and at 'isAuthenticated()'

If the token exist on that device, then its pretty good chance that in the past ( depending on expiration config on the token ) that they have logged in.

also may try:

```
ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getBoolean("emailVerified");
```

if you were filtering to just users who have supplied email thats been validated...